# Count order lines by condition and calculate the percentage to total lines

Tags: abap

Experts,

Please let me know how to write the code in ABAP to implement the following logic?

From the below screenshot, for each "S_ORD_ITM", I have to determine if Order_Qty = Dlv_Qty. If yes, determine the total count of S_ORD_ITM for which Order_Qty = Dlv_Qty. In this example, for all 6 rows of S_ORD_ITM, Order_Qty = Dlv_Qty. So, this value would be 6. Lets says this as 'X' Next step is to find the total record count of S_ORD_ITM column. It is also 6 in this case. Lets says this as 'Y'.

My result should be [X/Y]*100.

In some cases, there could be total of 18 S_ORD_ITM, out of which only there exists only 6 records of S_ORD_ITM for which Ord_Qty = Dlv_Qty. So, my result would be [6/18]*100 = 33.33%

This logic has to be implemented for delivery numbers which have a first pass indicator as 'X'. Imagine this sales order has many delivery numbers, and the delivery number in this example is a first pass indicator with 'X'. I already have a loop statement in my end routine, that says

LOOP AT RESULT PACKAGE ASSIGNING RESULT FIELDS WHERE /BIC/FIRSTPASS = 'X'.

Please let me know how I can make use of this already available loop statement and implement the above logic.

Thanks a ton,
G.

Comment: I was unable to post the screenshot. Imagine Sales order, Plant, Shipping Point, Delivery Number, S_ORD_ITEM (Order Line Item), Ord_Qty, Dlv_Qty as the columns.

Comment: While I could probably find out what you mean, I have to say I'm not inclined to code your business requirements for you, especially if the problem is presented in a very specific question that is unlikely to help anybody else.

Comment: And what have you tried up to now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
This is the code that I used:

 SELECT doc_number plant ship_point dsdel_date s_ord_item deliv_numb /bic/zlord_qty /bic/zldlv_qty
   INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE it_doc_table
   FROM /bic/azord_dso00.

 SELECT doc_number COUNT( DISTINCT s_ord_item ) AS numr
   FROM /bic/azsd_o11000
   INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE it_count_table
  GROUP BY doc_number.

READ TABLE lt_min_flag WITH KEY doc_number = source_fields-doc_number
                                plant =  source_fields-plant
                                ship_point   = source_fields-ship_point
                                deliv_numb =  source_fields-deliv_numb
                                dsdel_date = source_fields-dsdel_date
                       INTO lt_min_flag_wa 
                       BINARY SEARCH.

CHECK sy-subrc = 0. CLEAR result.

IT_DOC_TABLE = VALUE /bic/azord_dso00( FOR ls_doc IN  it_doc_table WHERE ( doc_number = source_fields-doc_number AND plant = source_fields-plant AND ship_point = source_fields-ship_point AND deliv_numb = source_fields-deliv_numb AND dsdel_date = source_fields-dsdel_date AND /bic/zlord_qty = /bic/zldlv_qty ) ( ls_doc ) ).  
z_numr = lines( it_doc_table ).
READ TABLE it_count_table INTO wa_count_table WITH KEY doc_number = source_fields-doc_number.

IF sy-subrc = 0 AND wa_count_table-numr <> 0.
 result = ( z_numr / wa_count_table-numr ) * 100 .
ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

Hello Goutham,
You can solve the whole thing a lot easier. You just need to make a data flow from your DSO where the order data is, then you do a lookup. with that you loop through your result data and push just the extracted, aggregated rows in a new DSO. First build the target structure and the DSO and then use an expert routine / end routine with an abap coding like i described.

### END UPDATE

so the Structure is like

`sales_order, plant, shipping_point, delivery_number, s_ord_itm, ord_qty, dlv_qty`

in your result package variable. is that correct? without a screenshot it is very hard to know what you mean, do you mean a SAP BW transformation or just ABAP code?
you could add some helper-variables to your structure or do it in the loop, i prefer doing it in the loop. but first you have to sort your result package!

your coding should be something like this (pseudo code) where your x variable is v_counter_ord_itm and v_counter_ord_dlv is your y:

make some data definitions like

```
WA_RESULT.../END OF...  (build a workarea for sales_order, result)
T_RESULT (make an itab out of workarea)
WA (workarea with sales_order, counter_ord_itm, counter_ord_dlv)
```

> PSEUDO-CODE!!!

```
SORT RESULT_PACKAGE BY /BIC/SALES_ORDER
WA-SALES_ORDER = 0.
WA-COUNTER_ORD_ITM = 0
WA-COUNTER_ORD_DLV = 0
LOOP AT RESULT PACKAGE ASSIGNING RESULT FIELDS WHERE /BIC/FIRSTPASS = 'X'.
  IF WA-SALES_ORDER NE /BIC/SALES_ORDER.
    IF WA-SALES_ORDER NE 0.
      WA_RESULT-RESULT = WA-COUNTER_ORD_DLV / WA-COUNTER_ORD_ITM * 100.
      WA_RESULT-SALES_ORDER = WA-SALES_ORDER.
      APPEND WA_RESULT TO T_RESULT.
      CLEAR WA, WA_RESULT.
    ENDIF.
    WA-SALES_ORDER = /BIC/SALES_ORDER.
  ENDIF.
  WA-COUNTER_ORD_ITM = WA-COUNTER_ORD_ITM + 1.
  IF result_fields-ord_qty EQ result_fields-dlv_qty.
    WA-COUNTER_ORD_DLV = WA-COUNTER_ORD_DLV + 1.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

then you have the variables in your itab. for usage within data processing in sap bw, do another loop with a lookup to push the result data in a new field "result" (you have to add it in the output structure):

```
LOOP AT RESULT_PACKAGE ...
  LOOP AT IT_RESULT ASSIGNING <z>
   WHERE /BIC/SALES_ORDER = <z>-SALES_ORDER.
  RESULT_PACKAGE-RESULT = <z>-RESULT.
ENDLOOP
```

Comment: Hello, First of all I must thank you for your time for your response!. You are the first person to respond with an intent. Sorry, I could not post the screenshot as Stack overflow didn't allow me to do so. The source (DSO) should have the sales order, line items, deivery numbers, plant, shipping point, delivery dates, order quantity and delivery quantity in the required format first. Then I can try to implement your above logic in the code from the DSO to the cube.

Comment: Hello Goutham,
so we are speaking about something totally other from what your first question looked like.

Comment: @ above - I managed to write the code, and get this work! Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: thats great, please mark as solved and upvote my answer!

Comment: Well, while I certainly appreciate your help, I did not use the code that you posted to solve the issue.